# Does pymongo support batch query?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

We know that we can use the following python statement to execute batch insert into mongodb through pymongo :

```
db.foo.insert([{"_id" : 1377890}, {"_id" : 1377545}, {"_id" : 1377966}, etc ...])
```

where the parameter is a list. Motivated by this, I tried to execute a batch query using:

```
db.foo.find([{"_id" : 1377890}, {"_id" : 1377545}, {"_id" : 1377966}, etc ...])
```

, but I was given an error. So, does pymongo or mongodb support batch query using similar technique? If any other mongodb engine support batch query like above, please also tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as a list of dicts, but you should be able to use a [query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-conditions-using-query-operators) to achieve the same effect:

```
db.foo.find({"_id": {"$in": [1377890, 1377545, 1377966, …]}})
```

I confess I haven't actually tried this, but it's consistent with the MongoDB API and should work with pymongo as well.

Comment: I tried just now. Yes, it works (the _id-list can be any list variable)! Thank you very much!

Comment: In addition, the speed has increased at lease four times compared to the method in which I query the collection as a whole and filter the wanted _id using python language. What a cool technique!